# Requests.get showing different HTML than Chrome's Developer Tool

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a web scraping tool using python (specifically jupyter notebook) that scrapes a few real estate pages and saves the data like price, adress etc.

It is working just fine for one of the pages I picked out but when I try to scrape this page: [sreality.cz](https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?stari=mesic) (sorry, the page is in Czech but the actual content is not that important now) using reguests.get() I get this result:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ html.lang }}" ng-app="sreality" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">

 <!--- Nastaveni meta pres JS a ne pres Angular, aby byla nastavena default hodnota pro agenty co nezvladaji PhantomJS --->
 <title ng:bind-template="{{metaSeo.title}}">Sreality.cz • reality a nemovitosti z celé ČR</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Největší nabídka nemovitostí v ČR. Nabízíme byty, domy, novostavby, nebytové prostory, pozemky a další reality k prodeji i pronájmu. Sreality.cz">
 <meta property="og:title"       content="Sreality.cz • reality a nemovitosti z celé ČR">
 <meta property="og:type"        content="website">
 <meta property="og:image"       content="https://www.sreality.cz/img/sreality-logo-og.png">
 <meta property="og:description" content="Největší nabídka nemovitostí v ČR. Nabízíme byty, domy, novostavby, nebytové prostory, pozemky a další reality k prodeji i pronájmu. Sreality.cz">
 <meta property="og:url"         content="https://www.sreality.cz/">

 <meta ng-if="metaStatus.value" name="szn:status" content="{{metaStatus.value}}">

 <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">

 <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64" href="/img/icons/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?3">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/icons/favicon-96x96.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="/img/icons/android-chrome-manifest.json">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
 <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/img/icons/browserconfig.xml" />

 <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" ng-href="{{ rss.url }}" ng-if="rss.url">
 <link ng-repeat="lang in metaSeo.languages" rel="alternate" hreflang="{{lang.code}}" ng-href="{{lang.url}}">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css?2e96626">

 <!-- Begin Inspectlet Embed Code -->
 <script type="text/javascript" id="inspectletjs">
 window.__insp = window.__insp || [];
 __insp.push(['wid', 821249485]);
 __insp.push(["virtualPage"]);
 (function() {
 function ldinsp(){if(typeof window.__inspld != "undefined") return; window.__inspld = 1; var insp = document.createElement('script'); insp.type = 'text/javascript'; insp.async = true; insp.id = "inspsync"; insp.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://cdn.inspectlet.com/inspectlet.js'; var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(insp, x); };
 setTimeout(ldinsp, 500); document.readyState != "complete" ? (window.attachEvent ? window.attachEvent('onload', ldinsp) : window.addEventListener('load', ldinsp, false)) : ldinsp();
 })();
 </script>
 <!-- End Inspectlet Embed Code -->

 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
   document.createElement('popover');
   document.createElement('mortgage');
   document.createElement('vendor');
   document.createElement('hp-signpost');
   document.createElement('category-switcher');
   document.createElement('feedback');
   document.createElement('bottom');
   document.createElement('panorama');
   document.createElement('panorama-prev');
   document.createElement('sphere-viewer');
   document.createElement('sphere-viewer-prev');
   document.createElement('save-filter');
  </script>
    <![endif]-->

 <!-- Statistiky -->
 <script src="https://h.imedia.cz/js/dot-small.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   try {
    // Při přesměrování na hashbang URL (IE8-9) ztrácíme referrer,
    // který je potřeba pro správné počítání statistik.
    if (window.sessionStorage) { // někdo může mít DOM storage zakázaný
     var l = document.createElement('a');
     l.href = document.referrer;
     var referrerHostname = l.hostname;

     if (window.location.hostname != referrerHostname) {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('referrer', l.href);
     }
    }

    // Starý android (< 4.0) v kombinaci s angularem špatně pracuje s hashem v URL.
    // Považuje ho za součást query případně path.
    // Na takových zařízech se budeme tvářit, že žádný hash nebyl.
    if (parseInt((/android (\d+)/.exec(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) || [])[1], 10) < 4) {
     var hrefWithoutHashbang = window.location.href.replace('/#!', '');
     var hashIndex = hrefWithoutHashbang.indexOf('#');
     if (hashIndex != -1) {
      window.location.replace(hrefWithoutHashbang.substring(0, hashIndex));
     }
    }
   } catch (e) {}
  })();
 </script>

 <!-- API mapy.cz -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api4.mapy.cz/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">Loader.load(null, {poi: true, pano: true})</script>

 <!-- Login reklama -->
 <script src="https://i.imedia.cz/js/im3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="https://1.im.cz/software/promo/promo-sbrowser.js"></script>

 <!-- Rozkopírování SID cookie -->
 <script src="https://h.imedia.cz/js/sid.js"></script>

 <!-- Login -->
 <script src="https://login.szn.cz/js/api/login.js"></script>
 <script>
  login.cfg({
   serviceId: "sreality"
  });
 </script>

 <!-- KONFIGURACE -->
 <script src="/js/conf/config.js?2e96626"></script>

 <script src="/js/advert.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/all.js?2e96626"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.DOT) {
   var dotCfg = {
    service: 'sreality'
   };
   if (window.SrealityABTest && window.SrealityABTest.getVariant()) {
    dotCfg.abtest = window.SrealityABTest.getVariant();
   }
   DOT.cfg(dotCfg);
  }
 </script>

 <noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=?_escaped_fragment_="/>
 </noscript>
 <meta name="fragment" content="!" ng-if="metaSeo.showMetaFragment" />

</head>
<!--[if IE 8]>    <body class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <body class="notie8 ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<body class="notie8 notie9 lang-{{html.lang}}">
<!--<![endif]-->
 <div loading-line></div>

 <div page-layout>
  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Though it is different from the one I see when I look at the page in Chrome's developer tool - a part of the code is here (the whole code doesn't fit in here and uploadtext isn't working for some reason):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs" ng-app="sreality" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide{display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-block-transitions{transition:0s all!important;-webkit-transition:0s all!important;}.ng-hide-add-active,.ng-hide-remove{display:block!important;}</style>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">

 <!--- Nastaveni meta pres JS a ne pres Angular, aby byla nastavena default hodnota pro agenty co nezvladaji PhantomJS --->
 <title ng:bind-template="Byty na prodej Brno-město, posledních 30 dní • Sreality.cz" class="ng-binding">Byty na prodej Brno-město, posledních 30 dní • Sreality.cz</title>
 <meta name="description" content="284 realit v nabídce prodej bytů Brno-město s požadavky: posledních 30 dní. Vyberte si novou nemovitost na sreality.cz s hledáním na mapě a velkými náhledy fotografií nabízených bytů.">
 <meta property="og:title" content="Byty na prodej Brno-město, posledních 30 dní">
 <meta property="og:type" content="website">
 <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.sreality.cz/img/sreality-logo-og.png">
 <meta property="og:description" content="284 realit v nabídce prodej bytů Brno-město s požadavky: posledních 30 dní. Vyberte si novou nemovitost na sreality.cz s hledáním na mapě a velkými náhledy fotografií nabízených bytů.">
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?stari=mesic">

 <!-- ngIf: metaStatus.value --><meta ng-if="metaStatus.value" name="szn:status" content="200" class="ng-scope"><!-- end ngIf: metaStatus.value -->

 <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">

 <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64" href="/img/icons/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?3">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?3">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/icons/favicon-96x96.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
 <link rel="manifest" href="/img/icons/android-chrome-manifest.json">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">
 <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
 <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/img/icons/browserconfig.xml">
<!-- ngIf: rss.url --><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" ng-href="/api/cs/v2/estates/rss?category_main_cb=1&amp;locality_district_id=72&amp;suggested_regionId=-1&amp;suggested_districtId=-1&amp;estate_age=31&amp;locality_region_id=14&amp;category_type_cb=1" ng-if="rss.url" class="ng-scope" href="/api/cs/v2/estates/rss?category_main_cb=1&amp;locality_district_id=72&amp;suggested_regionId=-1&amp;suggested_districtId=-1&amp;estate_age=31&amp;locality_region_id=14&amp;category_type_cb=1"><!-- end ngIf: rss.url -->
```

I can see from the first html code that requests.get downloads that the page runs some scripts which probably cause the html to be different.

I already tried using urllib but the result html doc was still the same.

Is there a way to download the html I see when I open the page in Chromes's developer tool so I can scrape it?

Comment: As you thought, your crawler isn't executing the javascript code that will make the page look like in the chrome rendering. You will need to use a proxy that will execute the code for you. You shoul check Splash for Scrapy or Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If eventually data from that page you are after, you can get it very easily using selenium in combination with BeautifulSoup. It gives you all the links of apartments.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty/brno?stari=mesic")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
driver.quit()

for title in soup.select(".text-wrap"):
    num = "https://www.sreality.cz" + title.select_one(".title").get('href')
    print(num)
```