# Requests.get() returns different HTML to Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

In the interests of educational web-scraping I'm trying to parse some html but something I can't explain is happening. When I view the page's source code via developer tools in Chrome I see

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/static/bundles/es6/Consumer.js/54df4d9114a3.js" as="script" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

but when I load it in Python via  `requests.get(url, headers)` I get

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/static/bundles/metro/Consumer.js/54df4d9114a3.js" as="script" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

The difference is `es6` is `metro`. What may be causing this? What could cause the same url to return different static html?

I'm using an identical User-Agent string to what's shown in Dev Tools, so I suspect I could be missing some other header information.

```
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
    }
html_content = requests.get(url, headers).text
```

[image]

I'm aware of this question, with an almost identical title,
[Requests.get showing different HTML than Chrome's Developer Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995955/requests-get-showing-different-html-than-chromes-developer-tool), but it doesn't answer the question and I don't want to use Selenium or a Web Driver. I'm after speed.

Comment: The server may react on some difference in the sent header, probably the user agent.

Comment: #Michael Butscher, the user agent string is identical, is there more to it than that?

Comment: You should see in the Chrome developer tools that the browser usually sends some more header lines to the server.

Comment: @Michael Butscher, I've updated the question with the full list of browser header lines. Does anything stand out to you?

Comment: Hard to tell but "cookie" and the "accept..." header lines are worth a try.